# #[derive(Insertable)] is not implemented for `std::string::String`

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I get this error:

```
#[derive(Insertable, Queryable, Identifiable, Debug, PartialEq)]
         ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
```

when I try to compile this `struct`:

```
#[derive(Insertable, Queryable, Identifiable, Debug, PartialEq)]
#[table_name = "example_table"]
pub struct SigninLog {
    pub id: i32,
    pub user_group: UserRoleEnum,
    pub created_at: Option<SystemTime>,
    pub optional_data: Option<String>
}
```

Is it because it contains a custom `enum` or an `Option<String>`? And if that is the problem how can I solve it?

Comment: Please review how to provide a [MCVE]. For Diesel-related questions, [see its specific MCVE guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust-diesel/info). Providing the *schema* is vitally important. You haven't defined what `UserRoleEnum` is nor where `SystemTime` comes from. It's entirely possible that these fields aren't even needed, that's part of making it *minimal*.

Comment: did you fix this problem? @tandry syawaludin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In general, in order to be able to `#[derive(X)]` for a `struct`, all its members must implement `X` as well. This might not be the case with `Insertable`, because it is not a standard trait, but you might want to verify this; in your case [`Insertable`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.2.2/diesel/prelude/trait.Insertable.html) is not implemented for the `String` within `optional_data`; it is implemented for `Option<T>`, so the `Option` enclosing it is not an issue.

You might want to implement `Insertable` manually; I haven't used `diesel`, though - there might be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: actually, the type for optional_data is json in postgres. Do you know what is best type of struct for?

Comment: @tandrysyawaludin I would recommend looking into [Serde's JSON capabilities](https://serde.rs/json.html).

Comment: what if i wanna unstructured JSON? i mean whatever the structure which posted by user

Comment: "In order to be able to `#[derive(X)]` for a `struct`, all its members must implement `X` as well." That's not true. See [this crate of mine for an example](https://mcarton.github.io/rust-derivative/).

Comment: @mcarton you mean it's possible with some help from an additional crate, no?

Comment: @ljedrz well, `Insertable` isn't a standard trait, so it could just do whatever it wants

Comment: @mcarton ah, ok; you're right - I'll add an extra disclaimer. I'm not experienced with `diesel`, maybe someone else will be able to confirm it.

Comment: @mcarton and how to set type for unstructured JSON?